# Xubuntu loading slow after the session/password select

Tags: boot, xubuntu

I recently installed Xubuntu on my computer. I love the distro. Everything was fast, and then the bootup slowed down. It started taking a couple minutes for my user selected wallpaper to show and the menu to appear, basically do anything on the comp. I do not recall doing anything other than changing the swappiness. It did not affect it initially. Would that be something to affect it or are there other ideas that might have caused this sudden change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, changing swappiness can slow down your computer. It is the threshold at which the system will swap data from the ram to the hard drive in order to preserve space. Data can be found, read and written much faster in memory than on the hard drive. Therefore it is best to keep data in memory and only swap to the hard drive when memory is very low. By default, swappiness is set to 60 and changing this value will determine how the system behaves in these situations.

Increasing this value will cause the system to swap more often. Even when it may be unnecessary. It will be more likely that the data you are seeking has been swapped out of memory. As I said earlier file manipulation is much slower on a hard disk so even simple tasks may take much longer than normal to complete.

Decreasing this value will cause the system to avoid swapping data to the hard disk. Sometimes this is recommended to increase performance but this could backfire if you have little ram to begin with. So, low ram combined with a low swappiness value can result in a system that will run out of memory quickly, while being reluctant to free memory through swapping.

I would recommend that you return the swappiness value to the default of 60. Monitor how the computer behaves. Hopefully you will see improvement.

Comment: Going to switch it back. I did find this though... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/accountsservice/+bug/996791

Comment: Do you have Lightdm logs that look like that?

Comment: I do not know how to check.

Comment: It is located at /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log. Any time you hear something about log files 99% of the time it will be in /var/log. Run 'gksu leafpad /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log' in terminal to view it.

Comment: Ok. Give me a bit. I reinstalled and now am getting grub rescue errors. Tried reinstalling and it is not reading the thumb drive. I reinstalled because I know it was caused by an update now. Was just trying to narrow it down.

Comment: Reinstalled, and working on replicating the problem. Not fully updating just yet. I installed all the important updates and it is fine, so now I am just doing the recommended ones slowly to narrow it down. No log to give just yet.

Comment: It was the glib networking stuff. Those are the only things I did not update.

Comment: That's weird. My Xubuntu install just took a crap as well. Don't remember what my last update was, though. I don't recall glib being one of them. I may end up reinstalling as well.

Comment: I had to reinstall. Glib was not the problem. It is something with the recommended updates though.

Comment: Did you figure out what caused it? I just reinstalled now.

Comment: I think mine is hardware related. A failing hard drive to be exact.

Comment: My laptop has not had any hard drive issues. I will keep checking the recommended updates route.

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the swap use (very important!)
1.5. This is especially noticeable on computers with relatively low RAM memory (1 GB or less): they tend to be far too slow in Xubuntu, and Xubuntu accesses the hard disk too much. Luckily, this can be helped.

On the hard disk there's a separate partition for virtual memory, called the swap. When Xubuntu uses the swap too much, the computer slows down a lot.

Xubuntu's inclination to use the swap, is determined by a setting. The lower the setting number, the longer it takes before Xubuntu starts using the swap. On a scale of 0-100, the default setting is 60. Which is much too high for normal desktop use, and only fit for servers.

A detailed explanation can be found here (link dead? Then download this pdf file with the same content).

Now the how-to:

**1.** First make sure that you have installed the applications gksu and leafpad:

Menu button - Accessories - Terminal Emulator

Type (use copy/paste):

```
sudo apt-get install gksu leafpad
```

Press Enter and submit your password. Please note that the password will remain invisible, not even asterisks will show, which is normal.

**2.** Now check your current swappiness setting. Type in the terminal (use copy/paste):

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

Press Enter.

The result will probably be 60.

**3.** To change the swappiness into a more sensible setting, type in the terminal (use copy/paste):

```
gksudo leafpad /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Press Enter.

Scroll to the bottom of the text file and add your swappiness parameter to override the default. Copy/paste the following blue lines:

```
# Decrease swap usage to a more reasonable level
vm.swappiness=10
```

**4.** Close the text file and reboot your computer.

**5.** After the reboot, check the new swappiness setting:

Menu button - Accessories - Terminal Emulator

Type (use copy/paste):

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

Press Enter.

Now it should be 10.

Note: your machine might benefit from an even bigger decrease in swappiness. A useful rule of thumb might be this:

```
1 GB RAM or more: set swappiness to 10
Less than 1 GB RAM: set swappiness to 5
```

Comment: but i think its better leave swapping to 60 because when you decrease swaping you also decrease disk cashe memory space .